# What's the scancode of RCtrl+Apps?

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to remap RCtrl+Apps combo to Media Function Volume Increase, and I have already searched for internet rapidly and there's no matched answer or tutorial shows what it is, I even have no clue about what's the patterns of a scancode which contains combo.
Any help would be appreciated, my goal is to map Apps Menu key to Volume Decrease and Rctrl+Apps Menu combo reassign to Volume Increase. Thanks in advance.